# DropColumn if exists in GORM

Tags: go, go-gorm

Refering [this](http://jinzhu.me/gorm/database.html#migration)  help doc, there is a drop table if exists syntax `db.DropTableIfExists(&User{}, "products")` but for `db.Model(&User{}).DropColumn("description")` DropColumnIfExists doesn't exists. What should I use to implement DropColumn (if the column exists, otherwise not.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What should I use to implement DropColumn (if the column exists, otherwise not.)

To answer your question...

Go ahead with that. You can use `db.Model(&User{}).DropColumn("description")`.

**Just handle the errors gracefully.**  Remember, in Golang, [Errors are values](https://blog.golang.org/errors-are-values).

```
func main() {
    db.AutoMigrate(&User{})

    err := db.Model(&User{}).DropColumn("description").Error
    if err != nil {
        // Do whatever you want to do!
        log.Print("ERROR: We expect the description column to be 
drop-able")
    }
}
```

Under the Hood, gorm will [execute](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/blob/2a041971f90398b736ee91c32503d4563d1d0d9e/scope.go#L348) raw postgresql [query](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/blob/2a041971f90398b736ee91c32503d4563d1d0d9e/scope.go#L1136) if it [has no error](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/blob/2a041971f90398b736ee91c32503d4563d1d0d9e/scope.go#L351). Otherwise, it will [return the error](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/blob/2a041971f90398b736ee91c32503d4563d1d0d9e/scope.go#L93).

Comment: @YashGoel you should Mark this answer as the accepted answer if it helped you and worked.

Answer (score 1):

Update to Mohsin's answer as of 2021:

> What should I use to implement DropColumn (if the column exists, otherwise not.)

the current version (3.5.5) does no more support the syntax/api of 2017

From [GORM Migration Reference](https://gorm.io/docs/migration.html)

```
err = db.Migrator().DropColumn(&AuthUser{}, "name")
if err != nil {
    // Do whatever you want to do!
    log.Print("ERROR: We expect the description column to be drop-able")
}
```